# How to create searchBar globall search for codable JSON array value using Swift 4.2?

Tags: json, swift, tableview, uisearchbar

My Scenario, I am loading `JSON` data into `tableview` with help of Codable structure. Here, I am trying to add `Searchbar` by using `storyboard`. I don’t know how to sync `self.tableArray` data with search bar `filtered array`. Please provide some idea.

MY Codable Structure

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let id, userID, country, card: Int
    let category: Int
    let title, description: String
    let createDate
    let user: User

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case country, card, category, title, description
        case createDate = "create_date"

    }
}

struct User: Codable {
    let firstname, lastname: String
}
```

My JSON Code

```
do {
          let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:data!)
          self.tableArray = result.data

} catch {
          print(error)
          self.tableArray = []
}
```

My Tableview Code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return filteredData.count
        return tableArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

      let item = tableArray[indexPath.row]
      cell.name_label.text = ("\(item.user.firstname) " + "\(item.user.lastname)")
      cell.date_label.text = item.createDate

       return cell
}
```

SearchBar Code

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // When there is no text, filteredData is the same as the original data
        // When user has entered text into the search box
        // Use the filter method to iterate over all items in the data array
        // For each item, return true if the item should be included and false if the
        // item should NOT be included
        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? names : names.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: There's no code related to the searchbar in your question at all. What did you try?

Comment: Searchbar code updated @DávidPásztor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First need to Delegate Search bar so add it `UISearchBarDelegate`. In this method there is a function that check the text in searchbar did change or not . It is

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) { }
```

But first you need to declare a variable.

```
var isSearching = false
```

and add this function

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" { // 



        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else {
        isSearching = true
        newArray = tableArray.filter({ value -> Bool in
            guard let text =  searchBar.text else { return false}
           return value.title.contains(text) // According to title from JSON

        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

> newArray is the same tableArray but its empty one.

You need to check als `numberOfRowsInSection` . If you dont modify , it can give error like `Index of out of range`

Change it

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if isSearching {
        return newArray.count
    }
    else {
           return self.tableArray.count
     }




    return 0
}
```

**UPDATE**
: I think the problem is in this part.You need to add `isSearching` here also

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
   if isSearching{ 
   // Need to change according to newArray
   let item = newArray[indexPath.row]
   cell.name_label.text = ("\(item.user.firstname) " + "\(item.user.lastname)")
  cell.date_label.text = item.createDate

  }
  else {
  let item = tableArray[indexPath.row]
  cell.name_label.text = ("\(item.user.firstname) " + "\(item.user.lastname)")
  cell.date_label.text = item.createDate
  }
   return cell
```

}

Comment: Thank you @Omer tekbiyik

Comment: I am getting error    newArray = self.users.name.firstname.filter({ value -> Bool in
my array for JSON     var users = [User]() @Omer Tekbiyik

Comment: newArray must be like var nemArray = [Post]() like tableArray @devmikle

Comment: I am searching "Demo" name. I have three "Demo" list but after search only one showing also Tableview not reloading. I gave tableView.reload() but didn't reloaded. Please update your answer @Omer Tekbiyik

Comment: As per your code for me search only showing first index. @Omer Tekbiyik

Comment: @devmikle where did u declare var isSearching = false

Comment: above viewDidLoad I declared @Omer Tekbiyik

Comment: Please update me. I am waiting for your answer @ Omer Tekbiyik

Comment: Thank you I will check it @Omer Tekbiyik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188768/discussion-between-devmikle-and-omer-tekbiyik).

Comment: is this correct  var tableArray = [Datum]()
    var newArray = [Datum]() @ Omer Tekbiyik

Comment: @devmikle can give me some suggestion, I want to search multiple type like from title, description, userid and date. can you guide me how to use these type of search.